# Exposing Sequelize filtering mechanics on API

Tags: api, sequelize.js, knex.js

I've been looking into some Node ORMs for use with PostgreSQL lately, and would like to expose some type of flexible filtering on the front end.

I'm quite enjoying the flexibility provided by Sequelize's where/include filtering (e.g. filtering a model based on some relation N levels deep).

Is the filtering mechanism safe *at all* to expose to any front end API? I haven't had much experience with it, so I"m not sure what types of fields can be passed through to the filter query.

Otherwise, for more complex querying I may go with something like Knex instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally if you need to ask if it is safe to expose where/include parameter passing directly to your frontend, I would suggest you shouldn't do it. If you don't know how it will behave you'll end up fast leaking all your users and password hashes to the world.

So you'll be better covered by validating incoming filtering parameters and only after that pass them to the query. You can use for example json schema to validate the incoming parameters.

For example in [objection.js](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/) ORM this thing is handled in a way that you can give the query inside your code certain pattern what data user can include to response, and then incoming user input is automatically reduced to that subset (this works only when one requests additional relations to the requested row).

```
var houseWithPossiblePetsAndOwner = await House.query()
  .allowEager('[pets, owner]')
  .eager(eagerParamDirectlyFromEndUser)
  .where('id', id);
```

You could extend your preferred ORM to support that kind of extra method, which allows you to declare for the query which parameters can be passed to it from the user input.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I'm already on objection.js at the moment, which is perfect. I've only been tempted because sequelize (out of the box) allows you to do some pretty powerful queries using JSON DSL - which would require a decent sized work to replicate in objection. I'll work towards extending objection filtering instead, rather than switching over.